# How to convert country code to country name

Tags: php, xml, country-codes

I have results from XML for country , but the results are in ISO2 format.

EX: US   them to be into my database as full country name
EX: United States

Is there any script that can convert country codes into full country name , before I add them into my database.

I have searched over the internet but I can't find any results, only IP address to something.

Comment: Two-letter country codes are probably [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

Comment: Can you specify what technology you are using? I think you can do it with the CultureInfo class in C#, but that's totally useless to you if you're not doing .net

Comment: Its PHP , data from countries from XML comes as  ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 as Sjoerd say , i need them converted into full country names

Comment: Anyone??? Please. I hope you under-stain the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about any local script, since you'd have to manage the data and the mapping between values.  But there does appear to be a [public API](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx) that can be used.

Comment: Its PHP , data from countries from XML comes as ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 as Sjoerd say , i need them converted into full country names

Comment: @user1033986: This service appears to do exactly that.  It appears to be working on the Officially Assigned, Exceptionally Reserved, and Traditionally Reserved values here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Comment: Anyone??? Please. I hope you under-stain the question.

Comment: @user1033986: Maybe I don't understand the question... What specifically do you need?  If you need to translate this data then you'll either need a service that does it (like the one to which I linked) or a local package for it.  The local package will either need to be regularly updated or you will need to maintain the data yourself.  I don't know of any local package, but this service seems to work pretty well.